# Parse a Lambda in C#

Tags: c#, dynamic, lambda, expando

I want to convert a string containing an expression of a known signature `Func<dynamic, bool)` into a dynamic function I can call.

```
(x) => x.Age > 18  //Typecastable to Func<dynamic, bool>

var function = (Func<dynamic, bool>) Lamdba.Parse("(x) => x.Age > 18")
```

I'm looking for the equivalent of `Lambda.Parse`

Full code of what I'm trying to achieve below:

```
using System;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class DynamicModelTests
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //Illustration purpose... Working code
        dynamic model = new ExpandoObject();
        model.Age = 18;
        Func<dynamic, bool> isAdultRule = (x) => x.Age >= 18;
        IDictionary<string, object> dict = model;
        dict["IsAdult"] = (Func<bool>) (() => isAdultRule(model));
        Console.WriteLine($"Is Adult: {model.IsAdult()}");
        //Working code ends

        //Pseudo code starts... Pseudo only because it needs a working Lambda.Parse()
        Compose(model, "IsAdult",  "(x) => x.Age >= 18");
        Compose(model, "CanWatchRRated", "(x) => x.IsAdult()");
        bool isAdult = model.CanWatchRRated();
        bool result = ExecuteByName(model, "CanWatchRRated");
        Console.WriteLine($"Is Adult #2: {isAdult}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Same as Is Adult #2: {result}");
        //ends
    }

    public static void Compose(dynamic model, string ruleName, string expression)
    {
        var method = GetMethod(model, expression);
        var ruleCallExpression = $"() => method(model)";

        IDictionary<string, object> dict = model;
        dict[ruleName] = (Action) method;
    }

    public static Func<dynamic, T> GetMethod<T>(dynamic model, string expression)
    {
        return Lambda.Parse<dynamic, T>(expression); 
    }

    public static T Execute<T>(dynamic model, string expression)
    {
        return GetMethod(model, expression)(model);
    }

    //Should be called after compose... otherwise, throws MethodNotFound Exception
    public static T ExecuteByName<T>(dynamic model, string ruleName)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> dictionary = model;
        if(!model.ContainsKey(ruleName))
        {
            throw new MethodNotFoundException();
        }

        return (T) model.Invoke(ruleName);

    }
}

public class MethodNotFoundException : Exception
{
}
```

Is there a ready-made `Lambda.Parse()` that I can use?

Note #1:  The model must be of type '`dynamic`'. I'm using [Rick Strahl's libary](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/feb/08/creating-a-dynamic-extensible-c-expando-object) instead of rolling my own `DynamicObject` implementation

Note #2:  All the examples of `System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression` to parse expressions only seem to work with known types.  They didn't work for me with type '`dynamic`'. If it does for you I'm all ears.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would  you put this in database if it C# code: `(x) => x.Age >= 18`? What will you do if you decide to write a store procedure to return the data  for reporting purposes? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I'm building a rule editor where I want the end user to be able to create the expression.  It'll most likely to be a expression like this "Age > 18 and Sex = 'M'".  And I want to be able to reuse rules inside other rules.